# Datasource + .NET controls

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am using OpenEdge 10.2B and OpenEdge Architect and I did the following steps:

- created a form.
- added a .NET grid control and a button that I named gridCustomer and btnProcess.
- created a temp table like this:

  DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCustomer
      FIELD CustNo AS CHARACTER
      FIELD Name AS CHARACTER
      FIELD City AS CHARACTER.
- added an event ButtonClick event.

In this event, I am able to populate the temp-table but I could not assign it as a datasource like this:

```
ASSIGN gridCustomer:DataSource = THIS-OBJECT:ttCustomer.
```

I get the error message : **could not locate element ttCustomer in class**.

Is there an example or a documentation somewhere about how to populate a datasource of a .NET control?

Thank you very much!
Sebastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a BindingSource object that points to a buffer, query or prodataset handle:

```
gridCustomer:DataSource = new Progress.Data.BindingSource(BUFFER ttCustomer:HANDLE).
```

Look for *Progress.Data.BindingSource class* in the OpenEdge Help for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you! I was also able to user DevExpress controls with your solution.